# adding new user to mysql through php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Have problem with adding new user using mysql and php. Trying to find out how to done my problem probably all day, but I didn't this.

So I connect my db in connect.php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("MySQL are not launched? Could not connect to DB");
if(!$db) {
    die("Your DB variable probably has no \$db name. No DB launched");
}
if(!mysql_select_db("fdb",$db)) {
    die("wrong DB name");
}
?>
```

made html inputs where user try to make account:

```
<form method="post" action="reguser.php">
type username: <input type="text" name="user" size="22"/><br>
type password: <input type="text" name="password" size="15"/><br>
retype password: <input type="text" name="password2" size="15"/><br>
type e-mail: <input type="text" name="email" size="50"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

and when he pushes submit it checkes on all error (ex not same passwords) but the problem i get the same error could not register from checking mysql_query($SQL)

```
else {
$SQL = "INSERT into users(name, password, email) VALUES ('$user','$password','$email'";
mysql_query($SQL) or die('could not register');

print "your registration complete<br>";
}
```

Comment: You're missing a bracket at the very end of your query `VALUES ('$user','$password','$email')` by the way.

Comment: You habe to access the form values with `$_POST['form-field-name']`. And don't use `mysql`extension for PHP cause it's deprecated and gets removed with one of the next PHP version. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the CREATE USER statement, which gives them access TO MySQL.

Comment: Have you ever heard of function called `mysql_error()`, the one that tells you what MySQL thinks you did wrong? Hint: you have invalid SQL there because of two reasons - one, you're missing `)` at the end of your SQL and two - `password` is a reserved word.

Comment: Never **EVER** use fixed/pointless error messages when debugging, especially when you could have the system TELL you what's wrong by using mysql_error().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `)` here:

```
VALUES ('$user','$password','$email'";
```

Try this:

```
VALUES ('$user','$password','$email')";
```

That is most likely merely a syntactical issue.

Comment: yep this helped, thanks. Just sad that i spend most day time to find missing bracket

Comment: I know... I've been there too :)

Comment: @Sevar Using an IDE editor such as Notepad++ will help you in future coding to pair up braces, parentheses etc.

Comment: I use it but missed some how(